# not initialize tfs versionControlServer

Tags: c#, tfs

I have console program, which need download file from source control (local tfs 2012). But when I try initialize VersionControlServer, I see on debug, that this variable equal null. Can you help me fix this bug?

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(UrlSite));
VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
versionControlServer.DownloadFile(serverPath, localFile);//throw exception, because versionControlServer=null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VersionControlServer` may be null due to the credentials being used to query TFS being invalid.

One way to check is to verify the value of `TfsTeamProjectCollection.HasAuthenticated`. Another way is to call the `TfsTeamProjectCollection.Authenticate()` method. i.e.,:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(UrlSite));

bool hasAuthenticated = teamProjectCollection.HasAuthenticated;

// Authenticate will throw a WebException if invalid credentials/url submitted.
teamProjectCollection.Authenticate();

VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
versionControlServer.DownloadFile(serverPath, localFile);//throw exception, because versionControlServer=null;
```